# SQLite: Calculate how a counter has increased in current day and week

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a counter and timestamp in unixtime as showed below:

```
+---------+------------+
| counter | timestamp  |
+---------+------------+
|         | 1582933500 |
|    1    |            |
+---------+------------+
|    2    | 1582933800 |
+---------+------------+
|   ...   |     ...    |
+---------+------------+
```

I would like to calculate how 'counter' has increased in current day and current week.

It is possible in a SQLite query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `CTE` get the min and max timestamp for each day and join it twice to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select date(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') day,
    min(timestamp) mindate, max(timestamp) maxdate
  from tablename
  group by day
)
select c.day, t2.counter - t1.counter difference
from cte c
inner join tablename t1 on t1.timestamp = c.mindate
inner join tablename t2 on t2.timestamp = c.maxdate;
```

With similar code get the results for each week:

```
with cte as (
  select strftime('%W', date(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) week,
    min(timestamp) mindate, max(timestamp) maxdate
  from tablename
  group by week
)
select c.week, t2.counter - t1.counter difference
from cte c
inner join tablename t1 on t1.timestamp = c.mindate
inner join tablename t2 on t2.timestamp = c.maxdate;
```

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrCEvhdSPMeuaMNV4iCHKT/3

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have SQLite version >= 3.25.0 the [SQLite window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) will help you achieve this.

Using the `LAG` function to retrieve the value from the *previous record* - if there is none (which will be the case for the first row) a *default value* is provided, that is same as current row.

For the purpose of demonstration this code:

```
SELECT counter, timestamp,
LAG (timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY counter) AS previous_timestamp,
(timestamp - LAG (timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY counter)) AS diff
FROM your_table
ORDER BY counter ASC
```

will give this result:

```
1   1582933500  1582933500  0
2   1582933800  1582933500  300
```